# Skype for Business App SDK for iOS Desktop Sharing or Application Sharing

Tags: ios, skypedeveloper

I try to develop iOS native app by using Skype for Business App SDK.

Are there any way to show desktop sharing from SfB Client on Windows Desktop to participants iPhone by using this SDK? I checked all the classes listed in the website below. But I could not find appropriate class.

https://ucwa.skype.com/appsdk/reference/iOS/

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported. Please provide feedback request on User Voice if you would like to see this feature